# VSIX installation package

Tags: package, vsix

I have created a VSIX project which also has some class files. When installing the package I want to move the dll files to some other application folder. So may I know where I should write this code. Which class should I inherit and overide the methods such that copying of dll code can be executed after installing the package or during initialization of package.

Answer (score 0):

A VSIX project produces a .VSIX file that is used to install/deploy a Visual Studio extension. A .VSIX file is basically a .ZIP file with a manifest describing the sort of extension(s) contained in the payload.

The VsixInstaller is responsible for copying the files to a location that the Visual Studio IDE will find them. You have very little control as to where the files actually get placed. You can organize the file layout in the .VSIX, but you can't control where the payload is copied to.

If the extension is installed on a per user basis, the files will wind up in the users AppData folder, in a folder similar to:

C:\Users<*user*>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_*xxyyzz*\Extensions.

If the extension is installed on a per machine basis, they are copied under:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions

Sincerely,